# What does 'Past duration X.XXX too large' mean?

Tags: ffmpeg

When encoding H.264 using ffmpeg I get the following type of warnings en masse:

```
Past duration 0.603386 too large
Past duration 0.614372 too large
Past duration 0.606377 too large
```

What do they mean? I have not found anything clear online or in the ffmpeg documentation.

Comment: Please direct the ffmpeg questions to http://video.stackexchange.com/ beta. See the ffmpeg tag description.

Comment: @Ondra Even another stackexchange? I'm getting confused with those 100+ subsites, I'm not sure if that is a positive direction which stackexchange is heading to.

Comment: @mxmlnkn I agree, it makes you long for simpler times... :)

Comment: I think it is. StackOverflow is for programming, this is not programming. There is a Q&A site for video processing, this is a question about video processing. What's not to understand?

Comment: Also read the tag description.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I was getting thousands of these warnings with a particular encode. I was downscaling 1080p video to 480p. At an edit point, where there was some dodgy video due to a defect in the source laserdisc, these messages started coming up and then appeared for, I think, every frame thereafter. They went on and on, like this short excerpt:

```
Past duration 0.901115 too large=  535031kB time=00:54:15.06 bitrate=1346.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=19 speed=1.15x    
    Last message repeated 31 times
Past duration 0.901115 too large=  535031kB time=00:54:15.62 bitrate=1346.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=19 speed=1.15x    
    Last message repeated 34 times
Past duration 0.901115 too large=  535031kB time=00:54:16.21 bitrate=1346.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=19 speed=1.15x    
    Last message repeated 36 times
Past duration 0.901115 too large=  535338kB time=00:54:16.83 bitrate=1346.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=19 speed=1.15x    
    Last message repeated 39 times
```

The original ffmpeg invocation was this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 720x480 -c:v libx264 -preset slower \
                              -crf 17 -c:a copy -y output.mkv
```

Following suggestions here I first added `-framerate 60000/1001` to the input. That did not improve anything. I retained `-framerate` and added `-r 60000/1001` to the output. That still did not improve anything. Retaining both I finally added `-async 1 -vsync 1`. This resulted in my receiving a single warning, and that's all. That invocation was:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -framerate 60000/1001 -s 720x480 -c:v libx264 \
           -preset slower -crf 17 -c:a copy -y output.mkv \
           -r 60000/1001 -async 1 -vsync 1
```

The only difference I found in a detailed dump from MediaInfo was the removal of this line found in the original invocation but not in the second one:

```
Delay relative to video                  : -33ms
```

However, I checked A/V sync near the beginning of the files and near the end, and there was no discernible difference in sync between the two files. Their running times were also the same, but that was only measured to the nearest second, in VLC. So I checked the frame counts using ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mkv -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -
```

and looking for "frame=#" near the end of the output.

Turns out the source video was 375226 frames long, the original invocation yielded 375195 frames, and the second invocation yielded 375200. So the second invocation, with vastly fewer warning messages also dropped 5 fewer frames.

Subsequent testing showed that `-framerate` and `-r` were unnecessary, and just using the two sync flags was sufficient. This produced identical results to the second invocation above, so the third and simplest invocation I found to solve the problem is this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 720x480 -c:v libx264 -preset slower \
                   -crf 17 -c:a copy -y output.mkv -async 1 -vsync 1
```

And yet another file subsequently produced a bunch of these warnings even with the sync flags, but adding back the rate flags "fixed" it (only produced two instead of thousands of warnings).  So sometimes the second invocation works when the third doesn't.  For my immediate purposes I'm going to settle on the second invocation and hope it fixes most of these problems.

This was all with ffmpeg version 4.0.

Comment: Thank you for this! After days of having issues, `-async 1 -vsync 1` fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis @larryy very helpful

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer. Could you also explain what these sync flags actually do?

Comment: Even with the `-async 1 -vsync ` and also specifying or not specifying the input rate to convert a video I took with my phone to another format I still get these warnings. Do you have any idea what the problem might be related with in this case?

Answer (score 95):

One of the maintainers for the DVDStyler project on SourceForge said [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/dvdstyler/discussion/318795/thread/313fd7d6/) about it:

> FFMpeg versions after Jan 15 2015 often display this warning. It has
>   been added to warn about possible rate control distortion, otherwise
>   it does not cause any harm.

Comment: 'rate control distortion' is related to (mainly video) encoding and has no relation to this warning, which is about whether the output timestamp differs too much (relatively) compared to input timestamp

Comment: The first few times I got the warning I terminated the conversion , but this advice made me let it run and the warnings stopped after a while and the conversion completed successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 62):

This warning message appears when trying to encode a high frame rate source to a low frame rate output, which means frames need to be dropped.

---

I had this error because I wanted to convert a series of images to a video:

```
ffmpeg -i %05d.png -r 24 -c:v libx264 -crf 5 out.mkv
```

The problem seems to be, that if no frame rate is give for the input, then a frame rate of 25 fps is assumed:

```
Input #0, image2, from 'frames/%04d.bmp':
  Duration: 00:00:15.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 920x650, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

This also can be seen on the total number of frames encoded. I had 400 images, but the above command only encoded 384:

```
frame=  384 fps= 68 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10931kB time=00:00:15.91 bitrate=5626.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=15    
video:10928kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.033807%
```

The error messages disappears by setting the input frame rate instead if the output frame rate. The output frame rate will then be automatically chosen to be that of the input. Additionally in newer ffmpeg versions you have to watch out, because when using PNG images with the `-i` option or rather the `image2` or `v4l2` input format, you have to use `-framerate` instead of `-r`, see the [documentation for the `-r` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options).

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i %05d.png -c:v libx264 -crf 5 out.mkv
```

It is also possible to specify the frame rate of both input and output separately:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i %05d.png -r 10 -c:v libx264 -crf 5 out.mkv
```

In this case only 161/400 frames will be encoded. The other frames interim will be dropped.
Also the error message disappears, I guess in order to not slow down ffmpeg by spamming to stdout, see:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4700
- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4401

Comment: "because only when using PNG images with the -i option, you have to use -framerate instead of -r" - this solved my issue completely, thanks!

Comment: In trying to convert a wmv to mp4, using `-r` worked where using `-framerate` did not.

Comment: +1 and I suggest to move your "summarize" at the top. More, as it solved my case of converting images to video and trying to incresase output framerate and speeding up output too. I started from this `ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" -r 50 "$( date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")-timelapse-x4-50fps.mp4"` to this with no more warning `ffmpeg -framerate 50 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" -r 50 "$( date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")-timelapse-x4-50fps.mp4"` (note the `-framerate 50` added for input)

Answer (score 52):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffmpeg.c) it seems to be that the difference between the presentation time (pts) in the input stream differs from the one in the output stream by more than a fixed limit set to 0.6 .

Snippets from the source:

```
    delta0 = sync_ipts - ost->sync_opts;
    delta  = delta0 + duration;
```

...

```
        if (delta0 < 0 &&
        delta > 0 &&
        format_video_sync != VSYNC_PASSTHROUGH &&
        format_video_sync != VSYNC_DROP) {
        double cor = FFMIN(-delta0, duration);
        if (delta0 < -0.6) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_WARNING, "Past duration %f too large\n", -delta0);
        } else
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Cliping frame in rate conversion by %f\n", -delta0);
        sync_ipts += cor;
        duration -= cor;
        delta0 += cor;
    }
```

This is only a quick glance, so please feel free to dig deeper.

Comment: Is there anything we can do to "fix" this issue, or explicitly set the output pts?

Comment: I don't remember the details surrounding this issue, but if by "fix" you mean getting rid of the warning then based on the above code you could look into the option `format_video_sync = VSYNC_DROP` or `format_video_sync = VSYNC_PASSTHROUGH` and see if one of those is viable in your use case.

Comment: Thanks.  I found out the setting the frame rate explicitly using the `-r` switch "fixed" these warnings.

Comment: Just something from personal experience: I had the "past duration" message spam problem and fixed that by forcing the input frame rate with -r 25, but then I started getting the audio heavily out of sync. Removing the -r option and using "-async 1 -vsync 1" to prevent audio desync has prevented the audio issue, but the "past duration" spam seems to be gone too.

Comment: In v 4.1 and later, the log level has been upgraded, so it will not appear at default log level.

Answer (score 0):

As per [FFmpeg issue #4700 -
Past duration 0.999992 too large](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4700)
it is only a warning.

Use `-loglevel` option to stop it:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i input_file.xyz ....
```

Possible levels are numbers or:

```
"quiet"
"panic"
"fatal"
"error"
"warning"
"info"
"verbose"
"debug"
"trace"
```

Answer (score 0):

The command should actually be:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i input_file.xyz ...
```

There is no "-" prefix to the "quiet" parameter, as it's not an option, rather a value for the "-loglevel" option.